# Determine the corresponding rate of increase of the water level height in the cylinder

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I go about doing this?

An ice cube of $16\,\text{cm}^3$ is melting on a mesh as shown below. Each side of the ice cube is
melting at a constant rate of $0.02\,\text{cm/s}$. Determine the corresponding rate of increase of the
water level height in the cylinder, when half of the volume of ice has melted, considering that
water expands by about $10\%$ when frozen. The cylinder has a radius of $2$ cm.

How do I start this? I'm quite bad at math so I'm not sure what formulas or rules to use.

Comment: This is a simple calculus problem. You have a rate of change of the sides of the cube, which translates to a non-constant rate of volume change. That volume of ice, when melted, corresponds to a volume of water (1.1 mL ice to 1 mL water).                           

The question asks for the rate of increase of the water height, which will not be constant (it will be quick to rise at first as the large ice cubes decrease in size quickly, and rise more slowly later on when the small ice cubes decrease in size slowly. This is a phenomenon most people are familiar with: ice melting in a drink).

Answer (score 0):

I can’t see the diagram but here is how you can get started:

First, an ice cube of initial volume 16 cm^3 has 6 sides, each melting at an equal rate of 0.02 cm/sec. This means that each face of the cube is approaching the center point of the cube at 0.02 cm/s, and therefore the ice cube is shrinking.

If S_t is the surface area of each side of the cube (in cm^2) at time “t” then the flow rate of melting ice $F_t$ is $6*0.02*S_t/1.1 $(accounting for water being 10% denser than ice).

If V_t ( in cm^3) of ice has melted (we assume equally from all sides) then the surface area at time “t” is given by:

$$ S_t = (16 -V_t)^{2/3} \implies F_t =  6*0.02*(16-V_t)^{2/3}/1.1$$

Now you just divide $F_t$ by the area of the cylinder to get the rate of rise.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Diagram of ice in cylinder]

For a cylinder, such as a cylinder of water held in a cylindrical glass, volume $V,$ radius $r,$ and height $h$:
$$V_\text{cylinder} = \pi r^2 h$$
Let's find the derivative with respect to $h.$ Since the formula is first order with respect to $h,$ the derivative is easy. It's just:
$$\frac {dV_\text{cylinder}}{dt} = \pi r^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$$

For a cube, volume $V,$ sidelengths $s:$
$$V_\text{cube} = s^3$$

The problem is a bit unclear on if s is decreasing at a rate of $0.02$ cm/s, or $2\cdot0.02$ cm/s. I'll solve as $0.02$ cm/s.

Take the derivative of the second equation:
$$\frac{dV_\text{cube}}{dt} = V_\text{cube}' = 3s^2 \frac {ds}{dt}$$
Use the above equation along with the rate of decrease from the problem statement ($0.02$ cm/s) to find the general equation for the change in volume of the cube:
$$\frac{dV_\text{cube}}{dt} = 3s^2 (0.02\text{ cm}/\text{s})$$
Now find the side length when half the volume of the cube has melted. When half the volume has melted, $V_\text{half} = (0.5)(16) = 8\text{ cm}^3 = s_\text{half}^3$
$$\implies s_\text{half} = \sqrt[3]{8} = 2$$
Now substitute this into the first equation we found:
$$\frac{dV_\text{cube}}{dt} = 3s^2 (0.02\text{ cm}/\text{s})$$
$$\implies \frac{dV_\text{half}}{dt} = 3(2)^2 (0.02\text{ cm}/\text{s}) = 0.24\text{ cm}^3/\text{s}$$
Now we have the rate of ice melting. multiply that by the scaling factor:
$$0.24\text{ cm}^3/\text{s of ice} = \frac 1 {1.1} 0.24\text{ cm}^3/\text{s} \text{ of water} = \frac {24}{110}\text{ cm}^3/\text{s of water}$$
Now we have the rate of volume of water appearing from the melted ice. Use the formula for the volume of a cylinder to find the rate of change of height:
$$\frac {dV_\text{cylinder}}{dt}= \frac {24}{110} \text{ cm}^3/\text{s} = \pi r^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$$
$$\implies \frac{dh}{dt} = \frac {24}{440\pi} \text{ cm}/\text{s}$$
Simplifying,
$$\frac {24}{440\pi} \text{ cm}/\text{s} = \frac {3}{55\pi} \text{ cm}/\text{s}$$